# How do I publish a WinUI3 msix bundle to the Microsoft Store

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winui-3

I've recently migrated my UWP app to WinUI3. However, I'm now struggling to upload it to the Microsoft Store.

If I upload an .msix package, the webpage tells me that because an earlier uploaded package was a .msixupload or .msixbundle, I can only upload one of them.

The App package wizard in Visual studio runs and produces .msix packages, but nothing I've tried has made it successfully produce a .msixupload or .msixbundle. The .csproj looks like:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.18362.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
    <Platforms>x86;x64;arm64</Platforms>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x86;win10-x64;win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <PublishProfile>win10-$(Platform).pubxml</PublishProfile>
    <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
    <EnableMsixTooling>true</EnableMsixTooling>
    <GenerateTemporaryStoreCertificate>True</GenerateTemporaryStoreCertificate>
    <DefaultLanguage>en-us</DefaultLanguage>
    <AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>True</AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
    <AppxBundlePlatforms>x86|x64</AppxBundlePlatforms>
    <AssemblyName>[App name]</AssemblyName>
    <UseAppLocalCoreFramework>true</UseAppLocalCoreFramework>
    <HoursBetweenUpdateChecks>1</HoursBetweenUpdateChecks>
    <AppxPackageSigningTimestampDigestAlgorithm>SHA256</AppxPackageSigningTimestampDigestAlgorithm>
    <GenerateAppInstallerFile>False</GenerateAppInstallerFile>
    <AppxSymbolPackageEnabled>True</AppxSymbolPackageEnabled>
    <GenerateTestArtifacts>True</GenerateTestArtifacts>
    <AppxPackageDir>[path]\App\AppPackages\</AppxPackageDir>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Instead, I've made an .msixbundle [manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps#create-your-app-package-upload-file-manually). However, when I try to upload it I get the error:
The package file format for [package name and version].0.msixbundle is invalid: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80510007

Does anyone know how to resolve this error or get visual studio to produce a .msixupload or .msixbundle that can be uploaded?

Even pointing me at a WinUI3 project that does produce bundles would be very helpful.

Comment: Dud you figure out this problem? I also stuck on this.

Comment: @steam3d In the end I've worked around the issue by wrapping the app in a packaging project (but would like to produce the bundles directly if possible).

Comment: I was able to make bundle manually using single packaged app. https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/discussions/3471#discussioncomment-5287437

Answer (score 1):

The general command you should be using is `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x86\MakeAppx.exe" bundle /d input_directorypath  /p <filepath>.msixbundle`

Ensure you don't have anything extraneous in your name between `<filepath>` and `.msixbundle`.  You've indicated above there is a `.0.` which may be causing your problems.